Remove all non alphanumeric and some specific characters from string of Google cloud API, preg_replace doesn't work
I'm getting a string from the API like this:
BLAPFEN L√

I'm trying to get rid of everything except alphanumeric characters, spaces and those characters: öÖäÄüÜß
This is what I'm trying:
$txt = trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9öÖäÄüÜß\- ]/', ' ', $txt));

and it's not working, that last character doesn't get removed.
It works when I put the string directly into a PHP file and try to remove it:
$txt = 'BLAPFEN L√';
$txt = trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9öÖäÄüÜß\- ]/', ' ', $txt));
echo $txt;

but why isn't it working with the text from the API?
The API is google cloud ocr if that matters and this is the code how I get it:
$txt = '';
$tadaa = $vision->annotate($img);
$obj = $tadaa->text();
if(isset($obj) && $obj[0] != null){
    $arr = $obj[0]->info();
    $txt = $arr['description'];
    $txt = str_replace(["\n\r", "\n", "\r"], ' ', $txt);
    $txt = str_replace('  ', ' ', $txt);        
    $txt = trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9öÖäÄüÜß\- ]/', ' ', $txt));
}

This is the image I have trouble extracting text from:


The issue you're facing is likely due to character encoding differences between the Google Cloud OCR API's response and what you're expecting in your PHP code. The character that looks like √ might not actually be a plain √ but a different encoding, which could be why preg_replace isn’t correctly matching it. To resolve this, you should ensure that the text from the API is properly encoded in UTF-8 before applying preg_replace.

Thanks for the hint, I've tried $txt = mb_convert_encoding($txt, "UTF-8", mb_detect_encoding($txt)); before preg_replace and it still doesn't work @HassaanAli

mb_detect_encoding() is a lie, what it actually is is mb_take_an_educated_guess_at_the_encoding() and it's frequently wrong. You get the source encoding from the documentation of the source's data.

It would also be helpful if you included what the OCR was supposed to read as that will help differentiate whether you're getting genuine junk data, or you're just dealing with an encoding mismatch.

@TheGreatCornholio You might try forcing the encoding if you suspect the API uses a consistent encoding. $txt = mb_convert_encoding($txt, 'UTF-8', 'auto');, Using 'auto' might be more effective as it checks several encodings. You can also specify a list of expected encodings.  $txt = mb_convert_encoding($txt, 'UTF-8', ['ASCII', 'JIS', 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', 'Windows-1252']); then the regex can be used as $txt = trim(preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9öÖäÄüÜß\- ]/u', ' ', $txt));

The 'auto' thing doesn't work, I'll try to guess the charset google is using. I now added the image which I have trouble with to the question. This is something a user of my app uploaded, so not my opinion or smth :D

I think extended characters can be multibyte, and as such you needed to use something like mb_ereg_replace() or one of the other multibyte functions.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

I don't understand how to use it, tried $txt = trim(mb_ereg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9öÖäÄüÜß- ]/', ' ', $txt)); but it doesn't work

@TheGreatCornholio You can use it like mb_ereg_replace(     string $pattern,     string $replacement,     string $string,     ?string $options = null ): string|false|null @Taoism answer is right as well.

Read more about mb_ereg_replace() on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php
